# How to set volume of audio object?

Tags: javascript, audio

I know that i can create an audio object like this:

```
var audio = new Audio("test.wav");
```

And i know how i can play the audio:

```
audio.play();
```

I used the following `for` loop to output all functions from `audio`:

```js
var myAudioObject = new Audio();

for (var key in myAudioObject)
{
   if (typeof myAudioObject[key] === "function")
   {
       console.log(key);
   }
}
```

But there is no setting for volume. Is it possible to change the volume in the audio object?

---

**HINT**

It was my fault. If i replace `function` in my for loop with `number` then i find volume.

```js
var myAudioObject = new Audio();

for (var key in myAudioObject)
{
   if (typeof myAudioObject[key] === "number")
   {
       console.log(key);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It's not a function, it's a property called `volume`.

```
audio.volume = 0.2;
```

The volume value is between 0 and 1:

- 1.0 means highest volume (100%. This is default)
- 0.0 means silent (like as mute)

[HTMLMediaElement volume <sup>*MDN*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume)

Comment: Thanks, my fault. If i replace `function` in my for loop with `number` then i  find volume.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```js
let music = new Audio({
    loop: true,
    volume: 1,
    src: ['/yourSounds/music.mp3']
})
```

it is easer to type

Comment: That does not work for me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40101071/14226613) works. 
_With Object.assign(document.createElement('audio'), {...})_

Comment: @TefoD That is because you are creating a new HTML/DOM element 'audio' and use that instead of just a JS object. There is a typo in this answer, as 'new audio()' returns 'audio is not defined', because it should be 'new Audio()' (capital A)

Comment: I've just tried this, and it doesn't work. The Audio constructor doesn't accept an object, it only accepts a string and I get an error if I pass an object.