# Create an audio element and give it properties inside an object literal

Tags: javascript, oop, audio, object-literal

I'm trying to get out of bad habits of writing spaghetti code. I found a great tutorial on [modular javascript](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f) and I'm trying to apply it to a project of mine.

I have this:

```
var sfx = {}

sfx.mySound1 = document.createElement('audio');
sfx.mySound1.src = 'https://some-url.ogg';
sfx.mySound1.moreProps = "...";

sfx.mySound2 = document.createElement('audio');
sfx.mySound2.src = 'https://some-url.ogg';
sfx.mySound2.moreProps = "...";
```

In another object I can play a sound effect like this:

```
sfx.mySound1.play();
```

I want to achieve the same thing but I want to use the object literal pattern:

```
const sfx = {
    mySound1: {
        // create audio element
        // give it props
    },
    mySound2: {
        // create audio element
        // give it props
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to create the audio element and give it properties in the same object. Maybe that defies logic and shouldn't work. If so, how should I write it instead to keep it all inside the `sfx object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var sfx = {
  mySound1: Object.assign(document.createElement('audio'), {
    src: 'https://some-url.ogg',
    moreProps: '...'
  }),

  mySound2: Object.assign(document.createElement('audio'), {
    src: 'https://some-url.ogg',
    moreProps: '...'
  })
}
```

> The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

Looks clear enough, but refer to [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) docs for browser compatibility and polyfill.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I ask for!

Babel has built in polyfill for `Object.assign()`.

My intention of using the Modular pattern and the Object literal pattern is to improve the quality of my code; robustness, maintainability and readability.

Is using `Object.assign()` like this bad practice in any way?

Comment: @Johan You could also use a self executing init function to do this but I don't see how this improves anything.

Comment: @Johan This is a valid use case for `Object.assign()`.

Comment: Worked for me as well - was searching for hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ya, you wouldn't be able to create the element and change it's properties in an object definition. I think your original way of doing it is just fine.

If you really wanted to, you could:

```
const sfx = {
    mySound1: document.createElement('audio'),
    mySound2: document.createElement('audio')
}

sfx.mySound1.src = 'https://some-url.ogg';
sfx.mySound1.moreProps = "...";

sfx.mySound2.src = 'https://some-url.ogg';
sfx.mySound2.moreProps = "...";
```

You could get weird with it and set the properties in separate objects and then use those objects to override the properties of the element object, but that would be bad weird, not good weird ;)