# How to onlooad play an audio

Tags: javascript, html

I have an audio file `audio` . on calling playaudio() function it plays.

`i want to play audio when window opens.`

how do i do it?

```js
window.onload = function(playAudio();)
var audio = new Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/audio-experiments/examples/elon_mono.wav");
  
function playAudio() {
audio.volume = 0.5;
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set volume of audio object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115491/how-to-set-volume-of-audio-object)

Answer (score 3):

To reduce the volume to half, simply do:

```
audio.volume = 0.5;
```

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume)

To autoplay the audio, just do:

```
audio.autoplay = true;
```

The property can either be `true` or `false`. [See here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_autoplay.asp)

Answer (score 2):

See here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume

There is a property called *volume* that you can change like this :

```
audio.volume = value;
```

the expected value is of type *double*

Comment: onload i want to play the audio how